# SQL Server default value does not appeared as entity default value

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity

Default value from SQL Server table's column does not appear in entity.

Is it normal behavior?

I have tried to figure it out but with no result.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Some examples? How do you insert values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework provides an explicit value for each property. In SQL you can write a query that inserts a value into `[Field1]` and leave `[Field2]` and `[Field3]` blank, and they will use the database default. But since Entity Framework generates the query based on the properties defined on the entity, all columns will always be given a value, so if you want to provide a default value, it will need to be set in the designer, I don't think it gets automatically picked up when the entity model is created.

Answer (score 2):

Entities have their own default values set in the designer.  Right click your entity and select properties to see the default value.

Answer (score 1):

you can tell entity framework that database will take care of that property by editing that property in SSDL of the edmx file.

**Initially**

`<Property Name="CompanyName" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40"  />`

**we have change it to**

`<Property Name="CompanyName" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" />`

by setting  storeGeneratedPattern="Computed" we can tell to EF that the property value will be inserted by DB.

For Editing SSDL

1. Right click the edmx file, open with XML(text) Editor.

2.Ctrl+F name of the property  and just change that property